# C++ binary fstream for read and write doesn't work

Tags: c++, fstream

Sample code below:

```
typedef struct myStruct 
{
     int field;
} MyStruct;
```

Function:

```
fstream infile (filename.c_str(), ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);
if (!infile.is_open())
{
    cout << "Error: Failed to open " << filename;
    return false;
}

MyStruct mystruc;
int size = sizeof(mystruc);

// get number of records in file
infile.seekg(0, ios::end);
int count = infile.tellg() / size;
infile.seekg(0,ios::beg);

for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
{
    infile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&mystruc), size);
    if (infile.good())
    {
        mystruct.field += 100;

        infile.seekp(size*-1, ios::cur);
        infile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&mystruc), size);
        //infile.flush(); 
    }
}

infile.close();
```

Say input file contains 4 MyStruct records with field values
1
2
3
4

Output is:
101
102
102
102

Instead of:
101
102
103
104

Why doesn't seekp work? It works it I flush after every write, but wouldn't flush slow down the function?

Comment: My guess -- Your problem likely has to do with they way C++ streams are buffered.  Flushing takes buffering out of the equation and then "works".  Yes, flushing will make the function slower, but in this trivial example you will be waiting on significant disk IO anyway.

Comment: I myself run into a lot of problems (such as experiencing that kind wtf retrievals after updating) some time ago, trying to use C++ streams in the base layer of a simple database library. I remember I changed that to cstdio (std::fopen, std::fread, std::fwrite, std::fseek, std::fclose), and everything worked magically again. Since then, I haven't used C++ streams again for nothing serious. Please note, I am not saying anything bad about C++ or its streams, it is just my experience.

Answer (score 0):

Your struct should be packed to a 1 byte boundry using `pragma pack`. Also, I am pretty sure you don't need the `typedef`.

Try something like this:

```
#pragma pack(push,1)
struct myStruct 
{
     int field;
}
#pragma pack(pop)  // return to original packing
```

Comment: I don't think that packing is required in this case, because size of int is a power of two, thus this structure will have the same size. Packing will not have any effect. It may or may not be needed depending on structure packing and portability requirements.  `typedef` is not needed though, it is C-style.